# Table does not exist, but it does exist

Tags: mysql, database

I am very new to SQL and I keep getting the error #1146 table does not exist, but it does exist. Can someone point me in the direction of where in my code the problem is.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Donut`
(
`DonutID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
`Description` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`price` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`DonutID`));

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Customer`
(
`CustomerID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`FirstName` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
`LastName` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
`Street` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
`Apartment` VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`City` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
`State` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
`zip` INT(5) NULL, 
`Homephone`BIGINT(12) NULL,
`Cellphone`BIGINT(12) NULL,
`Otherphone`BIGINT (12)NUll,
PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SalesOrder` 
( 
`DonutOrderID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`SpecialNotes` VARCHAR(35) NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
`date` DATETIME,
`CustomerID` INT NOT NULL, 
 Primary KEY(`DonutOrderID`,`CustomerID`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerID`) REFERENCES `Customer` (`CustomerID`)
 );
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SalesOrderDetails`
(
 `DetailsID` INT,
`qty` INT,
`DonutOrderID` INT,
`DonutID` INT,
PRIMARY KEY (`DetailsID`,`DonutOrderID`,`DonutID`),
FOREIGN KEY (`DonutOrderID`) REFERENCES `SalesOrder` (`DonutOrderID`) 
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION, 
FOREIGN KEY (`DonutID`) REFERENCES `Donut` (`DonutID`) 

);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `CustomerFullName`
 AS SELECT *, CONCAT('firstName',' ','lastName') AS customerFullName FROM    Customer;

CREATE INDEX `Donut_name_idx` ON `Donut` (`name` ASC);

INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Street, apartment,     City, State, Zip,Homephone,Cellphone,Otherphone)
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Smith', '12 Main street', 'A', 'Lumberton', 'NJ',   '08048','6092651212',null,null);
INSERT INTO Donut (DonutID, Name, Description, price) 
VALUES (1,'Chocalte Donut','Choclate',1.25);
INSERT INTO `SalesOrder` (DonutOrderID,CustomerID,SpecialNotes) 
VALUES (1,1, 'Make sure they are fresh!');
 INSERT INTO `SalesOrderDetails`(DonutOrderID, DonutID,qty)
 VALUES (1,1,3);
```

Here is the code for my query

```
SELECT Customer.FirstName, Customer.LastName, Customer.street,     Customer.apartment, 
Customer.city, Customer.state, Customer.zip,   Customer.Homephone,Customer.Cellphone,Customer.Otherphone, Donut.Name, Donut.Description, Donut.price,  
 SalesOrder.DonutOrderID, 
 Donut.DonutID, 
 SalesOrder.specialNotes,
 Customer.CustomerID,
 date 
 FROM `SalesOrder`,`SalesOrderDetails`
 INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetails.DonutOrderID ON SalesOrder=     SalesOrder.DonutOrderID
 INNER JOIN Customer  ON SalesOrder.CustomerID= Customer.CustomerID 
 INNER JOIN Donut ON `DonutID` = DonutID
```

Thanks

Comment: Your error is in `... INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetails.DonutOrderID`. You must join to a table, not a column, so it should be `INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetails ON SalesOrderDetails.DonutOrderID = SalesOrder.DonutOrderID`

Comment: The error message might be misleading, but the problem is definitely in the JOIN syntax

Comment: When I do that  it kept saying Not unique table/alias: 'SalesOrderDetails' so I tried altering the code to get a different error and that is when it says table DonutOrderID does not exist.

Comment: I agree the problem is in the join because I can build the schema so I know the creating tables part is working. What is the correct syntax for the join command so I can see all the information inserted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has several syntax errors including wrong `JOIN`s and accessing your columns with/without backticks inconsistently.

I've tried to improve it and here it is:

```
SELECT 
  c.`FirstName`, c.`LastName`, c.`Street`, c.`Apartment`, c.`City`, 
  c.`State`, c.`zip`, c.`Homephone`, c.`Cellphone`, c.`Otherphone`, 
  d.`name`, d.`Description`, d.`price`,  
  so.`DonutOrderID`, d.`DonutID`, so.`specialNotes`, c.`CustomerID`, o.`date` 
FROM `SalesOrder` so
INNER JOIN `SalesOrderDetails` sod ON so.`DonutOrderID` = sod.`DonutOrderID`
INNER JOIN `Customer` c ON so.`CustomerID` = c.`CustomerID` 
INNER JOIN `Donut` d ON d.`DonutID` = sod.`DonutID`
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am trying to learn so I understand c.`FirstName and so.`DonutOrderID.

Comment: If I want qty from SalesOrderDetails can I just add `SalesOrderDetails` sod on the same line FROM? I want to display `qty`

Comment: I believe you should read some basic tutorial about SQL. List the columns you want to retrieve in SELECT clause. so, sod, c and d are aliases for table names (shorter code)

Comment: Thank you @Consider Me for the help. I understand your code.